# Dependent Drop-down in Drupal Webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I need custom field in Drupal Web-form.

Requirement :-
I can select any Vocabulary in web-form setting.
On webform when I select Parent it should populate children below(Dependent Drop-down)

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the webform module you will find hierarchical select is not supported.   See here: [webform hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/node/329504#comment-6603384)

However, you can accomplish it by using the [webform conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) and the [webform term options module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_term_opts)  Create your list of vocabularies, then create the select lists pre-populated with the taxonomy terms, and set your conditions to show the select list if the correct option is selected from the main list.